# Metrics from AWS Serverless Aurora V2 cluster instances

Tags: aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using the Java CDK and creating readers and writers with

```
ServerlessV2ClusterInstanceProps writerProps = ServerlessV2ClusterInstanceProps.builder().stuff().build();
IClusterInstance writer = ClusterInstance.serverlessV2("writer", writerProps);

DatabaseCluster cluster = DatabaseCluster.Builder.create(scope, "Cluster").writer(writer)...
```

What would be the way of getting the metrics from the instances like mentioned in

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.AuroraMonitoring.Metrics.html ?

since the IClusterInstance is very generic and doesn't have any metrics functions. Neither can the cluster instance be cast to anything useable.

Thanks in advance,
Nik